# Zendesk Android SDK localization issue

Tags: android, localization, zendesk

I have a problem with localizing **Zendesk** to french. You can see in the below screenshot the word **Contacteznous** which is not the correct one.
[image]

This is not the only word that is incorrect, there are some english words which are not translated at all.
I think that based on the language, the appropriate words should be taken from values-fr file in **Zendesk** library package. The correct word sits there but is not used as you can see from the screenshot.

[image]

The code I use for setting up Zendesk is:

```
public void initZenDesk() {

        ZendeskConfig.INSTANCE.setDeviceLocale(Locale.FRANCE);
        ZendeskConfig.INSTANCE.init(getActivity(), Constant.ZenDesk_Support_Site, Constant.ZenDesk_ApplicationId, Constant.ZenDesk_Auth_CLientId,
                new ZendeskCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String s) {

                        Identity identity = new AnonymousIdentity.Builder()
                                .withNameIdentifier(globals.getUserDetails().get(Constant.MM_UserName))
                                .withEmailIdentifier(globals.getUserDetails().get(Constant.MM_Email))
                                .withExternalIdentifier(globals.getUserDetails().get(Constant.MM_UserId))
                                .build();
                        ZendeskConfig.INSTANCE.setIdentity(identity);
                        ZendeskConfig.INSTANCE.setContactConfiguration(new BaseZendeskFeedbackConfiguration() {
                            @Override
                            public String getRequestSubject() {
                                return "Support request";
                            }
                        });

                        new SupportActivity.Builder().show(getActivity());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ErrorResponse errorResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorResponse.getReason() + errorResponse.getResponseBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong, I followed the steps from the official **Zendesk** webpage. Everything is properly set in the admin back office as well. What am I missing guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing hyphen is a subtle bug in our translation file, thanks for pointing it out! It will be fixed in our next release.

The hyphen you see in the strings.xml file is a soft hyphen, `U+00AD` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen), instead of a regular hyphen, `U+2010`. As such, it is not displaying in this case, because the text is not being broken over multiple lines.

As a workaround in the meantime, you can override the `contact_fragment_title` in your app, making sure to use a real hyphen character (or a space, or whatever you prefer).

Comment: Can you give me some guidance on how to overwrite it please  ? :) 
What about some of the titles which are not translated? For example instead of  "Prendre une photo" the app is showing "Take Photo".

Comment: Create a String resource in your app under the values-fr folder, with the name "contact_fragment_title". Then put whatever value you want in there.

Comment: Where are you seeing "Take Photo"?

Comment: I am sorry, not "Take Photo", but "Camera" in the add attachment modal popup when you are making a new ticket.

Comment: You can override those strings too:
<string name="belvedere_dialog_gallery">Gallery</string>
<string name="belvedere_dialog_camera">Camera</string>

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a ticket open with us at the moment. We'll be looking at the issue tomorrow and we'll get back to you on that channel. We can post the result back here too.

Thanks,
Barry.